# Understanding DEL2 function in Matlab in order to code it in C++

Tags: c++, function, matlab

in order to code the DEL2 matlab function in c++ I need to understand the algorithm. I've managed to code the function for elements of the matrix that are not on the borders or the edges. 
I've seen several topics about it and read the MATLAB code by typing "edit del2" or "type del2" but I don't understand the calculations that are made to obtain the borders and the edges.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to approximate u'' knowing only the value of u on the right (or the left) of a point.
In order to have a second order approximation, you need 3 equations (basic taylor expansion):

u(i+1) = u(i) + h u' + (1/2) h^2 u'' + (1/6) h^3 u''' + O(h^4)

u(i+2) = u(i) + 2 h u' + (4/2) h^2 u'' + (8/6) h^3 u''' + O(h^4)

u(i+3) = u(i) + 3 h u' + (9/2) h^2 u'' + (27/6) h^3 u''' + O(h^4)

Solving for u'' gives **(1)**:

h^2 u'' = -5 u(i+1) + 4 u(i+2) - u(i+3) + 2 u(i) +O(h^4)

To get the laplacian you need to replace the traditional formula with this one on the borders.

For example where "i = 0" you'll have:

del2(u) (i=0,j) = [-5 u(i+1,j) + 4 u(i+2,j) - u(i+3,j) + 2 u(i,j) + u(i,j+1) + u(i,j-1) - 2u(i,j) ]/h^2

**EDIT** clarifications:

The laplacian is the sum of the 2nd derivatives in the x and in the y directions. You can calculate the second derivative with the formula **(2)**

u'' = (u(i+1) + u(i-1) - 2u(i))/h^2

if you have both u(i+1) and u(i-1). If i=0 or i=imax you can use the first formula I wrote to compute the derivatives (notice that due to the simmetry of the 2nd derivative, if i = imax you can just replace "i+k" with "i-k"). The same applies for the y (j) direction:

On the edges you can mix up the formulas **(1)** and **(2)**:

del2(u) (i=imax,j) = [-5 u(i-1,j) + 4 u(i-2,j) - u(i-3,j) + 2 u(i,j) + u(i,j+1) + u(i,j-1) - 2u(i,j) ]/h^2

del2(u) (i,j=0) = [-5 u(i,j+1) + 4 u(i,j+2) - u(i,j+3) + 2 u(i,j) + u(i+1,j) + u(i-1,j) - 2u(i,j) ]/h^2

del2(u) (i,j=jmax) = [-5 u(i,j-1) + 4 u(i,j-2) - u(i,j-3) + 2 u(i,j) + u(i+1,j) + u(i-1,j) - 2u(i,j) ]/h^2

And on the corners you'll just use **(1)** two times for both directions.

del2(u) (i=0,j=0) = [-5 u(i,j+1) + 4 u(i,j+2) - u(i,j+3) + 2 u(i,j) + -5 u(i,j+1) + 4 u(i+2,j) - u(i+3,j) + 2 u(i,j)]/h^2

Del2 is the 2nd order discrete laplacian, i.e. it permits to approximate the laplacian of a *real* continuous function given its values on a square cartesian grid NxN where the distance between two adjacent nodes is **h**.

h^2 is just a constant dimensional-factor, you can get the matlab implementation from these formulas by setting h^2 = 4.

For example, if you want to compute the *real* laplacian of u(x,y) on the (0,L) x (0,L) square, what you do is writing down the values of this function on an NxN cartesian grid, i.e. you calculate u(0,0), u(L/(N-1),0), u(2L/(N-1),0) ... u( (N-1)L/(N-1) =L,0) ... u(0,L/(N-1)), u(L/(N-1),L/(N-1)) etc. and you put down these N^2 values in a matrix A.

Then you'll have
ans = 4*del2(A)/h^2, where h = L/(N-1).

del2 will return the exact value of the *continuous* laplacian if your starting function is linear or quadratic (x^2+y^2 fine, x^3 + y^3 not fine). If the function is not linear nor quadratic, the result will be more accurate the more points you use (i.e. in the limit h -> 0)

I hope this is more clear, notice that i used 0-based indices for accessing matrix (C/C++ array style), while matlab uses 1-based.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it is a bit clearer :)
There are still a few things I'm not clear about:
What is h^2 in these equations and how can I get it knowing only the matrix u?
When I want to calculate the values on the first column (j=0) what should I do with "+u(i,j-1)"?
Likewise when j=max, what to do with "+u(i,j+1)"?
"+ 2 u(i,j) [...] - 2u(i,j)" seeing that this equals 0, is it a typing error?
Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I had to go through it a couple of times for understanding it properly but I'm all good now. I've compared the results between these equations and what matlab returns on an example and it matches. And I've been able to understand the calculations. Your explanation is very good and very understandable.   
 Thanks!!

Comment: +1 for good explanation! By the way can the del2 operator that is given in MATLAB be computed any faster ?

Answer (score 1):

DEL2 in MatLab represents Discrete Laplace operator, you can find some information about it [here](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/del2.html).

The main thing about the edges is that elements in the interior of the matrix have four neighbors, while elements on the edges and corners have three or two neighbors respectfully. So you calculate the corners and edges the same way, but using less elements.

Comment: Actually I've already tried that but this is not how the del2 function calculates these values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module I wrote in Fortran 90 that replicates the "del2()" operator in MATLAB implementing the above ideas. It only works for arrays that that are atleast 4x4 or larger. It works successfully when I run it so I thought I would post it so that other people dont have to waste time making their own.

```
module del2_mod
implicit none
real, private                       :: pi
integer, private                    :: nr, nc, i, j, k
contains
! nr is number of rows in array, while nc is the number of columns in the array.
!!---------------------------------------------------------- 

subroutine del2(in, out)
real, dimension(:,:)            :: in, out
real, dimension(nr,nc)          :: interior, left, right, top, bottom, ul_corner, br_corner, disp
integer                         :: i, j
real                            :: h, ul, ur, bl, br
! Zero out internal arrays
out = 0.0; interior=0.0; left = 0.0;  right = 0.0;  top = 0.0;  bottom = 0.0;  ul_corner = 0.0; br_corner = 0.0;
h=2.0

! Interior Points
do j=1,nc
    do i=1,nr
    ! Interior Point Calculations
    if( j>1 .and. j<nc .and. i>1 .and. i<nr )then
        interior(i,j) = ((in(i-1,j) + in(i+1,j) + in(i,j-1) + in(i,j+1)) - 4*in(i,j) )/(h**2)
    end if
    ! Boundary Conditions for Left and Right edges
    left(i,1) = (-5.0*in(i,2) + 4.0*in(i,3) - in(i,4) + 2.0*in(i,1) + in(i+1,1) + in(i-1,1) - 2.0*in(i,1) )/(h**2)
    right(i,nc) = (-5.0*in(i,nc-1) + 4.0*in(i,nc-2) - in(i,nc-3) + 2.0*in(i,nc) + in(i+1,nc) + in(i-1,nc) - 2.0*in(i,nc) )/(h**2)
    end do
! Boundary Conditions for Top and Bottom edges
top(1,j) = (-5.0*in(2,j) + 4.0*in(3,j) - in(4,j) + 2.0*in(1,j) + in(1,j+1) + in(1,j-1) - 2.0*in(1,j) )/(h**2)
bottom(nr,j) = (-5.0*in(nr-1,j) + 4.0*in(nr-2,j) - in(nr-3,j) + 2.0*in(nr,j) + in(nr,j+1) + in(nr,j-1) - 2.0*in(nr,j) )/(h**2)
end do
out = interior + left + right + top + bottom 
! Calculate BC for the corners
ul = (-5.0*in(1,2) + 4.0*in(1,3) - in(1,4) + 2.0*in(1,1) - 5.0*in(2,1) + 4.0*in(3,1) - in(4,1) + 2.0*in(1,1))/(h**2)
br = (-5.0*in(nr,nc-1) + 4.0*in(nr,nc-2) - in(nr,nc-3) + 2.0*in(nr,nc) - 5.0*in(nr-1,nc) + 4.0*in(nr-2,nc) - in(nr-3,nc) + 2.0*in(nr,nc))/(h**2)
bl = (-5.0*in(nr,2) + 4.0*in(nr,3) - in(nr,4) + 2.0*in(nr,1) - 5.0*in(nr-1,1) + 4.0*in(nr-2,1) - in(nr-3,1) + 2.0*in(nr,1))/(h**2)
ur = (-5.0*in(1,nc-1) + 4.0*in(1,nc-2) - in(1,nc-3) + 2.0*in(1,nc) - 5.0*in(2,nc) + 4.0*in(3,nc) - in(4,nc) + 2.0*in(1,nc))/(h**2)
! Apply BC for the corners
out(1,1)=ul
out(1,nc)=ur
out(nr,1)=bl
out(nr,nc)=br
end subroutine

end module
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so hard! I wasted a few hours to understand and implement it in Java.

Here is: https://gist.github.com/emersonmoretto/dec8f7125c032775da0d

Tested and compared to the original function DEL2 (Matlab)

I've found a typo in sbabbi response:

```
del2(u) (i=0,j=0) = [-5 u(i,j+1) + 4 u(i,j+2) - u(i,j+3) + 2 u(i,j) + -5 u(i,j+1) + 4 u(i+2,j) - u(i+3,j) + 2 u(i,j)]/h^2
```

is

```
del2(u) (i=0,j=0) = [-5 u(i,j+1) + 4 u(i,j+2) - u(i,j+3) + 2 u(i,j) + -5 u(i+1,j) + 4 u(i+2,j) - u(i+3,j) + 2 u(i,j)]/h^2
```